# When I go into the sculpting mode I can't see the model in the Solid shading mode, unless I toggle X-Ray

Tags: sculpting

It seems to be like this by default. Every time I enter sculpt mode and want to use the solid shading mode, the model appears to be completely flat (looks like 2D). It appears okay when I toggle X-Ray or turn on the Cavity setting in viewport shading but that's not ideal, cause obviously it's affected by them. I want to be able to use it like anyone else would. It happens to every new file I open. I tried to reset Blender to factory settings- didn't do anything. I uninstalled it and installed it again from the original website- didn't help. Following someone's advice, I downloaded it from Steam and tried to use that instead. Now instead of being flat, the model is completely GONE. Again, it appears with X-Ray/Cavity on but never just by itself.

What am I supposed to do? Here is a screenshot. [image]